# What is a good way to handle jwt-simple decode errors?

Tags: node.js, jwt

I am using Express in NodeJS with JWT token authentication through jwt-simple. What is a good way to handle JWT decode errors?

Example: `jwt.decode(token,secret)`

Which throws an error if the decode fails (ex invalid token). Currently i am doing a try catch block, but something tells me there must be a better way...

Comment: The best way to handle exceptions is quite subjective. You might want to check [Folktale's Result monad](https://folktale.origamitower.com/api/v2.3.0/en/folktale.result.html) out. You could also use an Either monad.